# on click addClass selected overrule addClass on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, offset, addclass

I'm finding myself in a problem which I think has a easy solution but I cannot see... I have two functions to add a class called `selected` which highlights the buttons.

One function removes the class selected if present and adds the class to the button clicked:

```
var sidebarLinks = $('.js-sidebar a');

    // About section: Remove and add class on click
    sidebarLinks.on('click', function() {
        sidebarLinks.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
```

The other function adds the class selected if the user decides to scroll instead of clicking on the buttons. These buttons would highlight in a determined offset of the page:

```
    var buttonOne = $('.buttonOne');
    var buttonTwo = $('.buttonTwo');
    var buttonThree = $('.buttonThree');


// Select nav buttons if scrolling and not clicking the button
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        // About nav sidebar links
        var buttonOne = $('.js-polspotten-sidebar');
        var buttonTwo = $('.js-product-sidebar');
        var buttonThree = $('.js-designers-sidebar');

        // About sections top scroll position
        var currentTopPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
        var productsTopPosition = $('#products').offset().top;
        var designersTopPosition = $('#designers').offset().top;


        // polspotten selected depending on scroll position
        if (currentTopPosition >= currentTopPosition && currentTopPosition < productsTopPosition) {
            buttonOne.addClass('selected');
        }
        else{
            buttonOne.removeClass('selected');
        }

        // products selected depending on scroll position
        if (currentTopPosition >= productsTopPosition &&
            currentTopPosition < designersTopPosition) {
            buttonTwo.addClass('selected');
        }
        else{
            buttonTwo.removeClass('selected');
        }

        // designers selected depending on scroll position
        if (currentTopPosition >= designersTopPosition) {
            buttonThree.addClass('selected');
        }
        else{
            buttonThree.removeClass('selected');
        }

    });
```

The problem is that both interact at the same time as the click event creates scroll.

What I want is that if somebody clicks on the button the scroll function will not work. It will only work if the user scrolls himself.

Is this possible?

Comment: If the click on the button triggers a scroll, which updates the classes, why don't you just only use the scroll event and not bother with the click event?

Comment: @ZiNNED I would like to have both functions separated. This way once the page has been scrolled to a determined point the navigation then will show its active. Otherwise during the scroll the buttons will highlight while it scrolls, this shows a not wished effect.

Comment: Just a note, in your first `if` condition you have `if (currentTopPosition >= currentTopPosition...`, which will always be true.